# How to load same android app to device with different name

Tags: android, android-studio

Our company has developed a android app for our customer. I want to create a new app with different name with same source code. I have already changed the app name. But when ever I load this new app to my device from android studio it gives error saying "alredy a new version of app is running in your device".

I want to release the same app with different name to the app store.

Comment: update version code and name in manifest/build.gradle.

Comment: Change package name of the application, build and load in your device.

Comment: Android app is identified by the package name.. Change the package name so that it will be an new app totally.. Different apps with different package names can have same app name

Answer (score 1):

If you use android studio, use flavors to compile your app using different packages and different names

Have a look on this website : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts

Answer (score 0):

change package name of application in manifest also change app name.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the other answers here is an example for how to do this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // your config
    applicationId "com.packagename.appname"
  }

  productFlavors {
    release {
      // you config
      applicationIdSuffix "release"
    }

    debug {
      // you config
      applicationIdSuffix "debug"
    }
  }
}
```

for more, feel free to read [this manual](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)